# Java Regular Expression to get word or words that start with capital letter and ends with a specific word

Tags: java, regex

How do I write a regular expression that will match a word or a group of words that start with a capital letter and ends with a specific word.

Examples:

```
string = {"the company is named Oracle Corporation", 
           "JP Morgan & Chase Corporation is under pressure"}
```

I need to get the following: `"Oracle Corporation"` and `"JP Morgan & Chase Corporation"`

Comment: My current regex is "\\b(?:\\p{Lu}\\p{L}*\\W+){0,2}?Corporation\\b"

Comment: Looks like you are not interested in companies that have lower case names.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
'\s[A-Z].*Corporation\b'
```

`\s` matches whitespace.  `[A-Z]` matches a capital letter.  `.*` matches absolutely anything.  `Corporation` matches "Corporation".  `\b` matches the end of a word.

See also: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Answer (score -1):

THis might help you get started.  It is not a regex, but I think you'll have more flexibility with it.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "the company is named Oracle Corporation, and JP Morgan & Chase Corporation is under pressure";
        String[] split = test.split("\\s");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (String s : split) {
            if (s.substring(0, 1).matches("[A-Z&]")) {
                sb.append(s).append(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```